# Test to determine preferential distribution of samples in two groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, fishers-exact-test

I have data structured hierarchically in this way, where single observations ("Member") are grouped in larger groups:

```
Major_group    Member       Sample1    Sample2   Sample3
GroupA         Member1      5          0         2
GroupA         Member2      3          4         10
GroupA         Member3      2          0         0
GroupB         Member4      10         3         7
GroupB         Member5      23         5         9
```

And so on. For each sample, the observations are counts of specific features of Member1,2... etc. If no specific features are present, the value is 0.

I have two sets of observations between two different groups of samples (and groups have unequal size). My hypothesis is to determine if, at the `Major_group` level, there is a **preferential distribution** of non-0 counts for that major group in either of the two groups.

I thought of using the Fisher's Exact Test for this, by building matrices like (for example, for groupA; numbers are only examples):

```
            Sample_group1     Sample_group2
Affected    10                4
Unaffected  9                 5
```

Where for each group `Affected` is the number of non-0 counting samples (and `Unaffected` the number of samples with observations = 0).

My doubts of on this approach:

- is it "flattening" the contributions of individual members?
- is it actually correct for what I'm trying to do?

As a disclaimer: my statistics background can be lacking, I'm a biologist by background.